# Is there any C API in openssl to derive a key from given string

Tags: c, openssl

I need a C API in openssl library for deriving the Key from a given string. Where can i get sample source code for this?

Comment: do you mean openssl API for C? I thought OpenSSL is a library that has some API functions. correct me if i am wrong

Comment: What does your string look like? Could you provide an example?

Comment: What kind of key? Do you want to generate symmetric encription key based on some text password? E.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2 ?

Answer (score 5):

A standard algorithm to do this is PBKDF2 (an acronym for *Password-Based Key Derivation Function version 2*).  There is an implementation of PBKDF2 in OpenSSL, declared in `openssl/evp.h`:

```
int PKCS5_PBKDF2_HMAC_SHA1(const char *pass, int passlen,
                           unsigned char *salt, int saltlen, int iter,
                           int keylen, unsigned char *out);
```

When you are generating a new key you should use `RAND_bytes()` from `openssl/rand.h` to create the salt.  `iter` is the iteration count, which should be as large as your intended application can tolerate - at least something like 20,000.

Comment: How do I get the IV from this?

Comment: @user465139: You don't, you use another call to `RAND_bytes()` to generate an IV.

Comment: @caf is it safe to rely on RAND_bytes for generation of IV? Does openssl does it differently internally?

Comment: @saruftw: Yes, it is safe, RAND_bytes is a CSPRNG.

Answer (score 0):

I found [an example](http://www.mail-archive.com/openssl-users@openssl.org/msg54143.html) on how to generate a key from a password. The example dates from 2008, as far as I can tell this is still undocumented in OpenSSL. So let me post the full example source to help all those poor souls who try to use the OpenSSL API.

Please note that this is NOT my code, it comes from Marek Marcola! All credits are due to him.

```
/*
 * Example program on how to derive an encryption key from a password
 * corresponding to the RFC2898 / PBKDF2 standard.
 * Found in a 2008 mailing list posted by Marek Marcola:
 * http://www.mail-archive.com/openssl-users@openssl.org/msg54143.html
 */

#include <string.h>

#include <openssl/x509.h>
#include <openssl/evp.h>
#include <openssl/hmac.h>

int print_hex(unsigned char *buf, int len)
{
    int i;
    int n;

    for(i=0,n=0;i<len;i++){
        if(n > 7){
            printf("\n");
            n = 0;
        }
        printf("0x%02x, ",buf[i]);
        n++;
    }
    printf("\n");

    return(0);
}

int main()
{
    char *pass = "password";
    char *salt = "12340000";
    int ic = 1;
    unsigned char buf[1024];

    ic = 1;
    PKCS5_PBKDF2_HMAC_SHA1(pass, strlen(pass), (unsigned char*)salt, strlen(salt), ic, 32+16, buf);
    printf("PKCS5_PBKDF2_HMAC_SHA1(\"%s\", \"%s\", %d)=\n", pass, salt, ic);
    print_hex(buf, 32+16);

    ic = 1;
    EVP_BytesToKey(EVP_aes_256_cbc(), EVP_sha1(), (unsigned char*)salt, (unsigned char*)pass, strlen(pass), ic, buf, buf+32);
    printf("EVP_BytesToKey(\"%s\", \"%s\", %d)=\n", pass, salt, ic);
    print_hex(buf, 32+16);

    return(0);
}
```

Comment: [OpenSSL 1.1.0c changed the digest algorithm](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39637388/608639) used in some internal components. Formerly, MD5 was used, and 1.1.0 switched to SHA256. Be careful the change is not affecting you in both `EVP_BytesToKey` and commands like `openssl enc`.