# What does PKCS5_PBKDF2_HMAC_SHA1 return value mean?

Tags: error-handling, openssl, pbkdf2

I'm attempting to use OpenSSL's [PKCS5_PBKDF2_HMAC_SHA1](http://cvs.openssl.org/fileview?f=openssl/crypto/evp/p5_crpt2.c&v=1.25.4.3) method. I gather that it returns 0 if it succeeds, and some other value otherwise. My question is, what does a non-zero return value mean? Memory error? Usage error? How should my program handle it (retry, quit?)?

Edit: A corollary question is, is there any way to figure this out besides reverse-engineering the method itself?

Comment: A documentation update is on its way. Here's the wiki page: [`PKCS5_PBKDF2_HMAC(3)`](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Manual:PKCS5_PBKDF2_HMAC%283%29). It will take longer for the POD file to be added to mainline.

Comment: It looks like Matt Caswell committed the patch: [doc/crypto/PKCS5_PBKDF2_HMAC.pod](https://git.openssl.org/gitweb/?p=openssl.git;a=commit;h=b5450d63499af10569d5fe2977f70abf5d92bfa9).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> is there any way to figure this out besides reverse-engineering the method itself?

`PKCS5_PBKDF2_HMAC_SHA1` looks like one of those undocumented functions because I can't find it in the [OpenSSL docs](https://www.openssl.org/docs/). OpenSSL has a lot of them, so you should be prepared to study the sources if you are going to use the library.

---

> I gather that it returns 0 if it succeeds, and some other value otherwise.

Actually, its reversed. Here's how I know...

```
$ grep -R PKCS5_PBKDF2_HMAC_SHA1 *
crypto/evp/evp.h:int PKCS5_PBKDF2_HMAC_SHA1(const char *pass, int passlen,
crypto/evp/p5_crpt2.c:int PKCS5_PBKDF2_HMAC_SHA1(const char *pass, int passlen,
...
```

So, you find the function's implementation in `crypto/evp/p5_crpt2.c`:

```
int PKCS5_PBKDF2_HMAC_SHA1(const char *pass, int passlen,
                           const unsigned char *salt, int saltlen, int iter,
                           int keylen, unsigned char *out)
    {
        return PKCS5_PBKDF2_HMAC(pass, passlen, salt, saltlen, iter,
                                 EVP_sha1(), keylen, out);
    }
```

Following `PKCS5_PBKDF2_HMAC`:

```
$ grep -R PKCS5_PBKDF2_HMAC *
...
crypto/evp/evp.h:int PKCS5_PBKDF2_HMAC(const char *pass, int passlen,
crypto/evp/p5_crpt2.c:int PKCS5_PBKDF2_HMAC(const char *pass, int passlen,
...
```

And again, from `crypto/evp/p5_crpt2.c`:

```
int PKCS5_PBKDF2_HMAC(const char *pass, int passlen,
                      const unsigned char *salt, int saltlen, int iter,
                      const EVP_MD *digest,
                      int keylen, unsigned char *out)
{
    unsigned char digtmp[EVP_MAX_MD_SIZE], *p, itmp[4];
    int cplen, j, k, tkeylen, mdlen;
    unsigned long i = 1;
    HMAC_CTX hctx_tpl, hctx;

    mdlen = EVP_MD_size(digest);
    if (mdlen < 0)
        return 0;

    HMAC_CTX_init(&hctx_tpl);
    p = out;
    tkeylen = keylen;
    if(!pass)
        passlen = 0;
    else if(passlen == -1)
        passlen = strlen(pass);
    if (!HMAC_Init_ex(&hctx_tpl, pass, passlen, digest, NULL))
    {
        HMAC_CTX_cleanup(&hctx_tpl);
        return 0;
    }
    while(tkeylen)
    {
        if(tkeylen > mdlen)
            cplen = mdlen;
        else
            cplen = tkeylen;
        /* We are unlikely to ever use more than 256 blocks (5120 bits!)
         * but just in case...
         */
        itmp[0] = (unsigned char)((i >> 24) & 0xff);
        itmp[1] = (unsigned char)((i >> 16) & 0xff);
        itmp[2] = (unsigned char)((i >> 8) & 0xff);
        itmp[3] = (unsigned char)(i & 0xff);
        if (!HMAC_CTX_copy(&hctx, &hctx_tpl))
        {
            HMAC_CTX_cleanup(&hctx_tpl);
            return 0;
        }
        if (!HMAC_Update(&hctx, salt, saltlen)
            || !HMAC_Update(&hctx, itmp, 4)
            || !HMAC_Final(&hctx, digtmp, NULL))
        {
            HMAC_CTX_cleanup(&hctx_tpl);
            HMAC_CTX_cleanup(&hctx);
            return 0;
        }
        HMAC_CTX_cleanup(&hctx);
        memcpy(p, digtmp, cplen);
        for(j = 1; j < iter; j++)
        {
            if (!HMAC_CTX_copy(&hctx, &hctx_tpl))
            {
                HMAC_CTX_cleanup(&hctx_tpl);
                return 0;
            }
            if (!HMAC_Update(&hctx, digtmp, mdlen)
                || !HMAC_Final(&hctx, digtmp, NULL))
            {
                HMAC_CTX_cleanup(&hctx_tpl);
                HMAC_CTX_cleanup(&hctx);
                return 0;
            }
            HMAC_CTX_cleanup(&hctx);
            for(k = 0; k < cplen; k++)
                p[k] ^= digtmp[k];
        }
        tkeylen-= cplen;
        i++;
        p+= cplen;
    }
    HMAC_CTX_cleanup(&hctx_tpl);

    return 1;
}
```

So it looks like `0` on failure, and `1` on success. You should not see other values. And if you get a `0`, then all the `OUT` parameters are junk.

---

> Memory error? Usage error?

Well, sometimes you can call `ERR_get_error`. If you call it and it makes sense, then the error code is good. If the error code makes no sense, then its probably not good.

Sadly, that's the way I handle it because the library is not consistent with setting error codes. For example, here's the library code to load the `RDRAND` engine.

Notice the code clears the error code on failure *if* its a 3rd generation Ivy Bridge (that's the capability being tested), and does not clear or set an error otherwise!!!

```
void ENGINE_load_rdrand (void)
{
    extern unsigned int OPENSSL_ia32cap_P[];

    if (OPENSSL_ia32cap_P[1] & (1<<(62-32)))
    {
        ENGINE *toadd = ENGINE_rdrand();
        if(!toadd) return;
        ENGINE_add(toadd);
        ENGINE_free(toadd);
        ERR_clear_error();
    }
}
```

---

> How should my program handle it (retry, quit?)?

It looks like a hard failure.

---

Finally, that's exactly how I navigate the sources in this situation. If you don't like `grep` you can try [`ctags`](http://ctags.sourceforge.net/) or another source code browser.

Comment: By "How should my program handle it?", I meant, does it mean that OpenSSL did something wrong (logic error), or does it mean that I did something wrong (usage error)? Or something else (e.g., memory error)?

Comment: @dafrazzman - right, it depends on the failure. But OpenSSL does not give you a return value to differentiate. It sucks, but that's the way it is.