# PKCS5_PBKDF2_HMAC: binary password

Tags: c, openssl, pbkdf2

I am going to use PKCS5_PBKDF2_HMAC to derive keys. Password argument is `const char*`. Does it mean it must consist of printable characters only? Can I use binary password instead? [OpenSSL Documentation](https://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/PKCS5_PBKDF2_HMAC.html) says nothing about it. The only clue is using char instead of unsigned char, but nothing more:

```
 int PKCS5_PBKDF2_HMAC(const char *pass, int passlen,
                   const unsigned char *salt, int saltlen, int iter,
                   const EVP_MD *digest,
                   int keylen, unsigned char *out);
```

[RFC](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2898.txt) mentions *P* shortcut for `password, an octet string`. Does it mean I can use a binary password being encoded as a hex string?

Comment: I don't know about `PKCS5_PBKDF2_HMAC()`, but apparently, you can use binary password in the form `"10110010101"`, you should be okay, as long as you supply a `const char *`.

Comment: You should be able to use any sequence of `passlen` octets you feel like using. the algorithm doesn't care. It is just going to combine it with the salt and send it spinning through the work-function abyss regardless.

Answer (score 1):

> Does it mean it must consist of printable characters only?

NO.

*If* its a binary password, then that means you have to specify its length in `passlen`. You *can't* set `passlen` to -1 because `strlen` won't work as expected.

---

> Can I use binary password instead?

YES.

Be sure to specify the length in `passlen`.

---

> Does it mean I can use a binary password being encoded as a hex string?

YES.

There's no difference between raw octets, Hex encoding, Base32 encoding or Base64 encoding. They are presentation formats, and they all have the same entropy. The entropy will be extracted by the derivation functions.

The different encodings will result in different derived keys, but all the derived keys will have the same amount of entropy.

---

Related, see [What does OpenSSL's PKCS5_PBKDF2_HMAC_SHA1 return value mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22851828/608639) for an analysis on the function. It was provided before OpenSSL provided the documentation on the function.

Also see other related questions, like [How to use PKCS5_PBKDF2_HMAC_SHA1()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9771212/608639).